# Prove that the sequence $\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}$ converge to $\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Plese check my proof and point the mistake :)

$$\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}< \epsilon$$

$$\frac{6n+2-6n-15}{4n+10}< \epsilon $$

$$ 13\left |\frac{-1}{4n+10}  \right |< \epsilon $$

$$ \left |\frac{-1}{4n+10}  \right |< \frac{\epsilon }{13} $$

Choose $$N \geq \frac{\epsilon }{13}$$

$$ \left |\frac{-1}{4n+10}  \right |< \frac{\epsilon }{13}\leq N $$

then

$$ |S_{n}-\frac{3}{2}|<\epsilon  $$

Comment: You need absolute values...

Comment: Sorry. I'm forgot

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with $N$. I think you need to find an integer $N$ with the property that if $n≥N$ then $$ \left |\frac{-1}{4n+10}  \right |< \frac{\epsilon }{13}\tag{$\star$}$$ but you don't seem to have any argument about that, and in general $(\star)$ will not true for every $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you are making is in the step: you derived that reciprocal of $4n+10$ should be less than $\epsilon/13$. For this to happen $4n+10$ must be bigger than the reciprocal of $\epsilon/13$.

This happens if $ n > \big(\frac{13}\epsilon -10\big)/4$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon >0$.

By Archimedean property, we know that there is a positive integer $N$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}<\frac{4\varepsilon}{13}$.

If $n \geq N$, we have

$$\left| \frac{3n+1}{2n+5}-\frac 32 \right|= 13 \left| \frac{-1}{4n+10}\right| \leq \frac{13}{4N+10}<\frac{13}{4N}<\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

It is increasing (try taking the derivative). It never assumes 3/2. It suffices to show it assumes arbitrary value slightly less than 3/2, 3/2-e. Consider the equation 
(3n+1)/(2n+5) = 3/2-e . After cross multiplying you get a linear equation which has a solution.